# Pushing to Heroku through HTTP

Tags: git, heroku, continuous-integration

I'm trying to deploy to Heroku using github actions,

and I just found that I can push my source codes by this line

`git push https://heroku:$HEROKU_API_TOKEN@git.heroku.com/$HEROKU_APP_NAME.git origin/master:master`

I tried to find references about this method, but I couldn't find one on Heroku's official docs.

How is this even possible?

Comment: It's probably not documented because Heroku wants you to use `heroku` CLI. But it works because that's how it's internally implemented. Start with `git remote -v` to list remotes with URLs.

Comment: Heroku stores credentials in `~/.netrc`: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication. And it stores exactly that: login and auth token.

Comment: @phd thank you for the explanation! I should've looked into that file but it makes all sense now.